# Returning the column number that has an error in the insert command

Tags: oracle

I have the following code

```
insert into emp(empno,ename,deptno)

select 
      t.col001,t.col002,d.deptno 
from 
     testselect t
     left join dept d on d.code=t.dept_code
where t.linenum=3
```

I want it to tell me which column has a problem when there is a problem in inserting information. For example, when it gives the error message invalid number, which column number has this error.

In fact, I want to write a program that tells the end user where the error is, so I want to write the exact location of the error with a program to show the user.

I created a page that uses apex_data_parser to enter information through an Excel file. That's why I want to show which column of Excel data has a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does it anyway; though, not by telling you a column *number* (I presume you're talking about its *position* in `select` statement's column list), but actually marking that column.

For example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (empno       number,
  3     ename       varchar2(10),
  4     deptno      number
  5    );

Table created.
```

I'll try to insert job name (`emp.job` is a `varchar2` column, containing values like CLERK or MANAGER) into `test.empno` whose datatype is `number`, so it'll raise *invalid number* error:

```
SQL> insert into test (empno, ename, deptno)
  2    select e.job, e.ename, d.deptno
  3    from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  4    where e.sal > 2000;
  select e.job, e.ename, d.deptno
         *                                <-- this asterisk
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

See the asterisk pointing to `e.job`? That's the culprit.

---

Tool I used is SQL*Plus.

Comment: In fact, I want to write a program that tells the end user where the error is, so I want to write the exact location of the error with a program to show the user.

Comment: End user will - I presume - use some front-end application written in ... what? Oracle Apex, the old Forms, or whatever other tool you might be using. If you don't want users to try to insert invalid datatype data, control it there. For example, choose *date picker* item for dates, *number* for salaries, *char* for first and last names, etc. That tool (let's suppose it is Apex) will then warn users that they entered wrong value and won't allow them to perform INSERT at all, until errors are fixed. So, once it actually comes to INSERT, it'll work just fine.

Comment: The problem is that I am not designing a form, I created a page that uses apex_data_parser to enter information through an Excel file. That's why I want to show which column of Excel data has a problem.

Comment: Aha. Perhaps you should load data into VARCHAR2 columns (so that everything from Excel file gets loaded), and then (in a separate procedure you'd write) parse row-by-row & column-by-column to find what data is wrong. Finally, you'd report what you found to users.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.
You have 3 tables, and 3 columns.
In the insert statement you have 1 table (emp) and 3 columns (empno,ename,deptno).
In the select statement you have 2 tables (testselect, dept) and 3 columns (col001, col002, deptno).

All that you need to do - describe data types for your columns, like that:

| Table insert | Column insert | Data type insert | Table select | Column select | Data type select |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| emp | empno | ? | testselect | col001 | ? |
| emp | ename | ? | testselect | col002 | ? |
| emp | deptno | ? | dept | deptno | ? |

So, after you fill this table, you will be able to realise, which data types compatible and which are not (and this incompatibility can raise your error).

Comment: This code I wrote is a simple example to describe the topic I want.
Otherwise, in reality, the information to be entered is more than 30 columns.
So I need to find out which column has error.

Comment: Not a problem - just fill 30 columns in my table.... another variant - cut insert by 1 field, and add one more until you get the error.